# Merge tags "behavior" and "discipline"?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tags **discipline** and **behavior** are nearly identical. Should they be merged? Which one should "survive"? The other one would remain as synonym for the first.

[Discipline](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discipline):

> How to enforce the rules you set for the child, and consequences when those rules are broken.

[Behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior):

> How to ensure or avoid certain behavior, and discussions about why children act the way they do.

I do see a difference in the above definitions, but as they are now I think they're not different enough to justify two separate tags. **Either we need to update the definitions to make the differences clearer, or they should be merged.**

Comment: As defined above, I think discipline and behavior are synonyms -- however, I'm not sure "behavior" couldn't be repurposed for more general behavioral questions.

Comment: Agreed, that's not the definition of "Behavior" I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggested change of definition:

**Discipline** stays as it is, but the tag wiki gets a pointer to the *behavior* tag:

> How to enforce the rules you set for the child, and consequences when those rules are broken. See the tag [behavior] about why children act the way they do.

**Behavior** is changed to focus only on the "why" while the "how" is directed toward the *discipline* tag:

> Discussions about why children act the way they do. See the tag [discipline] about enforcing your rules.

Comment: yeah, that's more like it.

Comment: I've done this now.